# count a specific number in a 3d list

Tags: python, list, 3d

I have created a 3d list. now I want to count the occurrences of numbers in that 3d list.

```
print("Enter matrix entries column wise one matrix after another:\n")
lists=[[[int(input()) for _ in range(o)] for _ in range(a)] for _ in  range(c)] 
print(lists)
```

I have done this code to create 3d list. Here o=4(number of rows),a=3(number of columns),c=2(number of matrix)(previously given by the user) and the matrix only contain 1,2,3,4 and 5.

```
Enter matrix entries column wise one matrix after another: 
 1 
 1 
 2 
 3 
 4 
 5
 1 
 2 
 3 
 4 
 5 
 1 
 2 
 1 
 1 
 1 
 1 
 1 
 1 
 2 
 2 
 3 
 3 
 4 
 4 
 [[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 1, 2]], [[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2, 2], [3, 3, 4, 4]]]
```

and I got this output and this is the desirable case. The resulted 3d list we can consider as

```
matrix1= 1 5 4
         2 1 5
         3 2 1
         4 3 2
matrix2= 1 2 3
         1 2 3
         1 2 3
         1 2 3
```

Now I want a 3d list say 'counts' which looks like this:

[[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1]], [[4, 0, 0], [0, 4, 0], [0, 0, 4], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]]

```
Here counts[0][0][0](i.e. first 1) describes how many 1's are there in first column first matrix.

counts[0][0][1](i.e. second 1) describes how many 1's are there in second column first matrix.

counts[0][0][2](i.e. third 1) describes how many 1's are there in third column first matrix.

counts[0][1][0](i.e. forth 1) describes how many 2's are there in first column first matrix.

counts[0][1][1](i.e. fifth 1) describes how many 2's are there in second column first matrix.

counts[0][1][2](i.e. sixth 1) describes how many 2's are there in third column first matrix.

counts[0][2][0](i.e. seventh 1) describes how many 3's are there in first column first matrix.

counts[0][2][1](i.e. eighth 1) describes how many 3's are there in second column first matrix.

counts[0][2][2](i.e. ninth 0) describes how many 3's are there in third column first matrix.

counts[0][3][0](i.e. tenth 1) describes how many 4's are there in first column first matrix.

counts[0][3][1](i.e. eleventh 0) describes how many 4's are there in second column first matrix.

counts[0][3][2](i.e. 12th 1) describes how many 4's are there in third column first matrix.

counts[0][4][0](i.e. 13th 0) describes how many 5's are there in first column first matrix.

counts[0][4][1](i.e. 14th 1) describes how many 5's are there in second column first matrix.

counts[0][4][2](i.e. 15th 1) describes how many 5's are there in third column first matrix.
```

In the same way [[4, 0, 0], [0, 4, 0], [0, 0, 4], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]] this part is also calculated for second matrix.
Please calculate 'counts' list from 'lists' list and 'a','o','c' variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what exact output you are looking for but, you can use for loops to achieve that:

```
lists=[[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 1, 2]], [[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2, 2], [3, 3, 4, 4]]]
for m_num, matrix in enumerate(lists):
    for ind, col in enumerate(matrix):
        for i in range(1, 6):  # because as you said matrix contains only 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5
            print('number of {} in column idn: {}, of {} matrix: {}'.format(i, ind+1, m_num+1, col.count(i)))
```

You can also skip enumerate and just print numbers of '1' in the first column, then in second column, etc:

```
lists=[[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 1, 2]], [[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2, 2], [3, 3, 4, 4]]]
for matrix in lists:
    for col in matrix:
        for i in range(1, 6):
            print(col.count(i))
```